# reactivate a checkbox in a dynamic list jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to reactivate a checkbox in a dynamic list and I do not succeed, the list update its contents every x time.

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="mylist">
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="check" checked>0</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="check">1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="check">2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="check">3</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="check">4</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="check">5</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="check">6</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="check">7</li>
    </ul>
</div>
// checkbox 
var checkbox;
var list = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
//
setInterval(function(){
    $('.mylist li').remove();
    for(i in list) {
        $('.mylist').append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="check">' + i + '</li>');
    }
    if(typeof checkbox === 'object')
        checkbox.prop('checked', true);
}, 3000);

$('.check').on('click', function(){
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     checkbox = $(this);
 }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ywkr5ezp/3/

Comment: Can you explain the problem?

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is very vague, and your code is... weird. What are you trying to achieve? Just a guess: are you trying to make it so that only one checkbox can be selected at a time? If so, don't use checkboxes, but radio buttons. https://jsfiddle.net/z1gbyj34/

Comment: Sorry for not being so explicit,
The list is reloaded every x time, the user selects by clicking a checkbox an item from that list.
As you can see the list is renewed.
The idea is to save the selected checkbox and re-check it when the list is re-created.

Someone mentioned that this happens because the element that I keep in the variable is not the same one that is recreated.
Apparently I have to reference it by some attribute.

Comment: @covi2 Could you give a bit more context and explain why you want to remove every checkbox and reload them every 3 seconds? Maybe it makes perfect sense to you, but from my point of view, I don't see any practical application where that would be needed. If you explain why, we might be able to point you to a better solution. Is this what you are trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/e3vwqg9w/

Comment: I have a list with 200 or more elements and each element changes its state each 1 minute. the states are obtained for a request to the server. me i seemed suitable remove the elements and render it to load but thinking well not is the but optimal. in the example use 3 seconds alone as example.each list has a checkbox, when the user active the checkbox the info of element remains visible in a popup. the popup sample the information that goes obtaining each the 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because the input element stored in `checkbox` is not the same as the new input element that you are creating. When you store an element in a variable it is storing that specific instance of the element.

One way around this would be to give the checkbox elements id's that you could then reference and recheck.